# RIA Services: Enumerate Deleted Entities

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ria, silverlight-toolkit

My RIA service context class has an entity set TaskToOperationAssociations which contains a list of Task to Operation associations.

Is there a way to "find" an association entity which has been removed from the collection? I can see that the context has a reference to the removed Association in it's private fields (it obviously needs to keep track of it so the delete operation can be submitted).

Here's an example...

If I have Task "A" (with Id=T1) which is associated to Operation X, Y and Z (with id's O1,O2 and O3) and task B (with Id=T2) is associated with the same operations then the collection will contain 3 TaskToOperationAssociations as follows...

1. Association A1, TaskId = T1, OperationID = 1
2. Association A2, TaskId = T1, OperationID = 2
3. Association A3, TaskId = T1, OperationID = 3
4. Association A4, TaskId = T2, OperationID = 1
5. Association A5, TaskId = T2, OperationID = 2
6. Association A6, TaskId = T2, OperationID = 3

I remove association A1 and catch the property change event of the TaskToOperationAssociations. In the event handler I want to find out if any of the associations for Task T1 have changed so I can enable a save button on the UI.

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this using only the context. I fixed it by wrapping the context and tracking deletions manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate ChangeSets, ChangeSet will contain everything before it was submitted. On server side, you can intercept OnSaveChanges and also enumerate ChangeSet.

For existing association changes, mostly changeset will contain change of Foreign Key. Your current Context's Entity Container will contain ChangeSets that are not submitted yet.

Comment: Yes! I can do context.EntityContainer.GetEntitySet<Association>().Where(x => x.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted). Thanks, I must have assumed that EntityContainer was useless or private when using quick watch when inspecting the available properties.

Comment: I'm removing this as Id' not fully tested it earlier andwhen I did come to test it, it didn't actually work

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your last comment? You will only see changes if you have called AcceptChanges or did IEditableObject.EndEdit on your entity, that will mark changes to be saved. Best time to call it will be OnSubmitChanges method to see the ChangeSets that are going to be submitted. For this you can create a partial class of your DBContext and override OnSubmitChanges method to inspect changes.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment doesn't make much sense, I was in a rush and clearly didn't read what I'd written. It's not a DBContext, it's a System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext. I want to enumerate the deleted entites before OnSubmitChanges to see if there are any changes to be submitted and so I can enable a button in the UI.

Comment: DBContext will be the class that will be created by RIA services that is derived from DomainContext, please click on Show all folders and see the cs file in grayed out Web folder, you will see name of class. You will have to create a partial class of same name that is your context. For example, if name of your service is OrganizationService in web project, then name of context will be OrganizationContext and create partial class and override On Submit changes.

Comment: I want to do this BEFORE i submit changes. I want to, at any point in time, look at my context and see if there are deleted items. How can I enable a save button which will then call SubmitChanges if I have to SubmitChanges before I can check if the save button can be enabled?

Comment: Well then instead of this, why dont you try Custom Validation on client side in RIA Services, you can provide a class that will validate before Accepting changes. EntityContainer and DomainContext has HasChanges property, once HasChanges turns true, you can then navigate changes in ChangeSets. http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/09/25/RiaServicesCustomValidationMethods.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work because the entity set will be HasChanges = true if any Associations have been been removed. I want to know if associations for a specific Task have been removed.

Comment: Can you try Custom Validator on the specific task?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you

```
var deleted = Context.EntityContainer.GetChanges().RemovedEntities
    .Where(re => re is TaskToOperationAssociations && ((TaskToOperationAssociations)re.GetOriginal()).TaskId == T1.Id)
    .Select(re => (TaskToOperationAssociations)re);
```

or just

```
var hasDeleted = Context.EntityContainer.GetChanges().RemovedEntities
    .Any(re => re is TaskToOperationAssociations && ((TaskToOperationAssociations)re.GetOriginal()).TaskId == T1.Id)
```

to find out if there are any deleted associations for T1

with

```
foreach (var assoc in deleted)
{
   Context.TaskToOperationAssociations.Add(assoc);
   ((IRevertibleChangeTracking)assoc).RejectChanges();
   ((IRevertibleChangeTracking)T1).RejectChanges();
}
```

you can completely undo the deletion (if you have not committed your changes yet)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Fabiano, I'm leaving this company tomorrow but I'll pass the answer onto the other guys to see if they can use it in future. Shame you didn't get here sooner as there was bounty to be had :)

Comment: are you sure that the RejectChanges code will work? It looks like your changing the collection you're enumerating :) I don't need to do that anyway but the other stuff looks great and compiles which is a nice start. I'll fully test it tomorrow.